# saga hangs when updating a redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, yield, redux-saga, saga

I was using `redux-saga` in my application. And use `saga` to set the state of my `redux`.
But one thing i am experiencing now is the application will hang if I use saga to update the `redux state` with a different value from its existing state

Lets say, in my `redux` there is state name `locale`. first i set it to `en`, and create an action `CHANGE_LOCALE` to change the `locale` state to `zh` later.

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  locale: 'en' <- set initial state to en
});

function languageProviderReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_LOCALE:
      return state
        .set('locale', action.locale);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**saga.js**

```
export function* loadProfile() {
  const profileURL = 'profile';
  const profile = yield axios.get(profileURL)
    // .then((res) => (res.data))
    .then((data) => (data.data));

  yield put({
    type: ACTION1,
    payload: profile,
  });
  console.log('finish action one');

  yield put({
    type: CHANGE_LOCALE,
    locale: 'zh', <- change to zh using saga
  });
  console.log('finish action two');

  yield put({
    type: ACTION3,
    payload: profile,
  });
  console.log('finish action three');
}
export default function* defaultSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(constants.LOAD_PROFILE, loadProfile);
}
```

So when I run the app, the `console.log` is just showing `finish action one`. Meaning it is hanging after changing the `locale` state of `Redux` .

( I use Redux Dev Tool to check and it actually has changed the `locale` state to`'zh'`, -> it actually finish the `action two` however , it seems like the `saga` dont know what to do next )

p/s: The programm will run sucessfully after hanging for 2 or 3 minutes , so its like saga is stuck and then keep retry after a few minutes and succeed 
Any help please ??

Comment: `put` effect silents errors that happen during its execution. I am assuming there is some error while rerendering your view. Try to call `store.dispatch({type:CHANGE_LOCALE, locale: 'zh'})` from console to see if your app throws an err.

Comment: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/550

Comment: This is something that is probably going to change in redux-saga@1.0.0 (see breaking changes in https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.0)

Comment: @MartinKadlec I was also tried to include the catch block to get the error, but it seems like there was no error there , it just somehow get cancelled after run the CHANGE_LOCALE, .

Comment: @MartinKadlec I also tried to change the redux-saga version but i dont think this is the reason